# I'm new to swift can someone explain how to use closures as rawValues for enums

Tags: swift, enums, closures

I'm new to swift can someone explain how to use closures as rawValues for enums.

```
enum Tpi:Function{
    case func1={()->Void in 

 print("say hi!")}
}

var xsel=Tpi.func1.rawValue
xsel()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Function` is not an existing type in Swift.

Swift enum can only inherit from `RawRepresentable` types so using a function as RawValue for an enum is not possible (and to be honest, a little bit weird).

Here is a way to achieve something similar:

```
enum Tpi {
    case func1

    var function: (() -> Void) {
        switch self {
        case .func1:
            return {
                print("say hi!")
            }
        }
    }
}

var xsel = Tpi.func1.function
xsel()
```